# Convert a WebExtensiions API (Chrome, Firefox) to Safari using Xcode 12

Tags: safari, firefox-addon-webextensions

Apple have announced that Safari on macOS 11 will support WebExtensions API - how does one do it?

Answer (score 0):

Found out by reading the description for [this WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10665).

Apparently there's a command-line tool. Run `xcrun safari-web-extension-converter --help` with Xcode 12 for more information.